# AWS send text SMS without using TopicArn or TargetArn (only mobile number) via php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, push-notification, sms, amazon-sns

I had been working on PHP module which needs to send text SMS to user mobile number. I had been googling around and found some article which says that AWS can send text message using only mobile number.

But my side i am always stuck with the following error:

> Invalid parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required parameter

Please help / guide me on above which the best approach to get it done and lastly that might integrate to send bulk SMS to using AWS.

I am open for any suggestions and your time is much appreciated.

Regards,
Shreyas

Comment: need to see the code you are using

Comment: best solution it's find another sms provider like https://www.twilio.com/sms/api

Comment: @ nogad

$sns = SnsClient::factory(array(
   'credentials' => array(
    'key'    => Configure::read("aws.s3_key"),
    'secret' => Configure::read("aws.s3_secret"),
   ),
   'region' => 'us-east-1'
  ));
  $result = $sns->publish(array(
   'PhoneNumber' => '+917597071917',
   'Message' => 'string',
   'Subject' => 'string',
   'MessageStructure' => 'string',
   'MessageAttributes' => array(
    'String' => array(
     'DataType' => 'string',
     'StringValue' => 'string',
     'BinaryValue' => 'string',
    ),
   ),
  ));

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which was resolved by upgrading the SDK from V2 to V3. It is version 3 that allows both the TopicARN and TargetARN to be undeclared.

Comment: some versions fo V3 also have the problem (3.3.8). Y updated to 3.87.1 and started working fine. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

AWS sends SMS by subscribing the number to a topic. This is typically used for alerting users within a "topic" that your instance is down or services are not working properly. Usually associated with an alarm.

Comment: That's _one way_ to send SMS. You can also send SMS directly to phone numbers without referencing a topic.